# SQLite file is empty

Tags: c#, sqlite, file

So... I'm working on project that requires small but quick access to database **file**. And now i can create file, but i'm not able to fill it. I'm calling queries that should create table, but file is still empty. Could please someone help me?

```
static class Database
 {
      private static SQLiteConnection _connection;
      public static bool Connected {
           get { return _connection != null; }
      }

      public static void Connect(string file)
      {
           _connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + file + ";Version=3;");
           _connection.Open();
      }

      public static void Disconnect()
      {
           _connection.Close();
           _connection = null;
      }

      public static SQLiteDataReader Query(string sql)
      {
           SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _connection);
           return cmd.ExecuteReader();
      }

      public static void ExecuteFile(string file)
      {
           foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file).Where(line => !line.Trim().StartsWith("--")))
           {
                Query(line.Trim());
           }
      }

      public static void Install(string file)
      {
           SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(file);
           Connect(file);

           // Installation
           ExecuteFile("install.sql");

           Disconnect();
      }
 }
```

I'm calling 'Install' method to create that database. And here is that install file:

```
-- Database configuration
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF 
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

-- Database schema creation
CREATE TABLE Metadata(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR(256), value VARCHAR(256))
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(256), parent VARCHAR(64)     REFERENCES T1(ID))
CREATE TABLE T2(ID VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, msg TEXT, userName VARCHAR(256), userEMail VARCHAR(256), userNick VARCHAR(256), t1 VARCHAR(256) REFERENCES T1(ID), position INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE ChangeRecords(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, changeAction INTEGER, filePath TEXT, data BLOB, position INTEGER, lenght INTEGER, t2 VARCHAR(64) REFERENCES T2(ID))
CREATE TABLE T3(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(256), url TEXT)

-- Metadata defaults
INSERT INTO Metadata (name,value) VALUES ('credentials_name','null')
INSERT INTO Metadata (name,value) VALUES ('credentials_email','null')
INSERT INTO Metadata (name,value) VALUES ('credentials_nickname','null')
INSERT INTO Metadata (name,value) VALUES ('prefer_nickname','false')
INSERT INTO Metadata (name,value) VALUES ('root','master')
INSERT INTO Branches (id, name) VALUES ('fc613b4dfd6736a7bd268c8a0e74ed0d1c04a959f59dd74ef2874983fd443fc9','master')
```

After all this file is still empty (0bytes)!

Comment: Where is the install.sql file located - is it in the same directory where the executable resides? Habve you tried to go step by step through your code (debugging it) to see what happens when the install function is called? Maybe an exception is suppressed or something like this?

Comment: I did tried to debug it, and i've found out that no data are wrote anywhere in code.

Comment: Do you have some kind of try/catch in the code that calls Database.Install? If yes do you properly show any error messages coming out from this code?

Comment: How and where is the `install`function called? Start with the install until your database is created!

Comment: There is not try/catch, and install method is called as first method in Main method (because project output is console)

Comment: Try to remove those empty lines in your input file.

Comment: Also the last line of that file contains an INSERT INTO a table that doesn't exist `Branches`

Comment: Fixing the above two comments allowed to run your code without errors and creates the file as expected. What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: I've fixed both problems and still file is empty. I'm using library 1.0.94.0 that uses SQLite 3.8.6

Comment: If you delete the empty file will it be recreated in that location? Not sure but it seems that you are looking to a different file

Comment: OK... that is weird. I've found that when program ends on its own, then is file filled. I guess that in that SQLite library some destructor is called that will flush all data.

Comment: Does anybody know what method should I call to flush all data

Comment: Try to change your code in the Disconnect. Call _connection.Dispose(); after close and before setting it to null

Comment: try wrapping your code that does your `Creates, Inserts, Updates, or Deletes` around a using(){} and prior to the executing call wrap that around a try{}catch{} to catch and database errors.. also objects that `implement IDisposable` if they are not inside the `using` then Dispose of them like this for example `((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();` looks like you need to seriously step thru the code and pin point where the exact error is happening.. also `null` have you thought about using `DBNULL,Value` in  your inserts..?

Comment: unless I am blind.. what is the sql command used in this line and where is it being called `public static SQLiteDataReader Query(string sql)`

Answer (score -1):

It toked a really long time but I've found solution. I've had to add `GC.Collect();` after 
`_connection = null;` so all destructors are called!

Comment: Thats no good solution. SQLiteConnection and SQLiteCommand both implement IDisposable. Make the connection not static,make it a local variable, and use it with a using block. If you do so, you will not need to wait for garbage collection...